# How to separate String values and object type values from object arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an arraylist

`private ArrayList<Object> myList = new Arraylist<>()`

This arraylist contains String values and SongInfoModel(object) values.

How to retrieve these two into their respective arraylists?

`private ArrayList<SongInfoModel> songList = new Arraylist<>()`

`private ArrayList<String> path= new Arraylist<>()`

I'm using below given code, but it is giving me error in the "add" statement

```
for(Object ob: myList){

        if(ob instanceof SongInfoModel)  {

            songList.add(ob); //error
        }else if(ob instanceof String){

            path.add(ob); //error
        }
    }
```

I know this is a noobish question, but please help me!

Comment: It might help posting (or reading if you haven't done so yet) the error.
Also, are your lists named correctly? You use `SongList` once and `songList` the second time. Similarly, `PathName` and `path` seemingly interchangeably

Comment: You can cast the objects after the instanceof

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the Objects:

```
for(Object ob: myList){

        if(ob instanceof SongInfoModel)  {

            songList.add((SongInfoModel)ob); //<--
        }else if(ob instanceof String){

            path.add((String)ob); //<--
        }
    }
```